# What are my options for 2D games on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, xna

So I've been playing around with XNA and after all this time, I finally made a game that's worth buying!

And to my surprise, I see **this** on MSDN:

> XNA Game Studio 4.0 apps that target Windows Phone OS 7.1 remain fully
>   supported and continue to run on Windows Phone 8 devices.
>
> •You can continue to develop and maintain new or existing XNA
>   Framework apps that target Windows Phone OS 7.1.
>
> •You can’t upgrade existing XNA Framework apps that target Windows
>   Phone OS 7.1 to target Windows Phone OS 8.0.
>
> •You can’t create new XNA Framework apps that target Windows Phone OS
>   8.0.
>
> When you select an XNA Game Studio 4.0 project template, you can only
>   choose Windows Phone OS 7.1 as the target operating system.
>
> •You can use certain XNA Framework assemblies in apps that target
>   Windows Phone OS 8.0.
>
> You can reference and use the following XNA Framework assemblies in
>   apps that target Windows Phone OS 8.0. You can’t reference or use
>   other XNA Framework assemblies that aren’t in this list in apps that
>   target Windows Phone OS 8.0.
>
> •Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll
>
> •Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices.dll
>
> •Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServicesExtensions.dll
>
> •Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch.dll
>
> •Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.dll
>
> •Microsoft.Xna.Framework.MediaLibraryExtensions.dll
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207003(v=vs.105).aspx

I'm only interested in making 2D games. I don't have the slightest idea about Direct X or Direct 3D (I would love to get into 3D but that will be yet another huge set back).

From the quoted text above, I see two things that really get on my nerves:

1. I **can** create new or maintain existing XNA games that target Windows Phone 7.1
2. But I can **not** create new XNA games that target Windows Phone **8**! **Why**??? Where is the sense in that???

So, naturally, my question now is:

What are my options for making 2D games (in Visual Studio) for Windows Phone OS 8? I think I saw an option that lets you use XAML for 2D games, correct me if I'm wrong about that but that feels extremely weird to me. I mean, XAML is very structured, I cannot imagine so much freeform objects being trivial to setup for a game.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using [Cocos2D](http://cocos2d.org/) and [Monogame](http://www.monogame.net/). The were born from iOS and Android development but now support WP8 and Win8. In addition you write your code once (C# + VS) and have a game for all platforms.

Comment: Hmmm. Sorry if this is uber stupid, but do you mean try cocos2d and monogame together, or try them separately? I mean, can I just use cocos2d without monogame?

Comment: Together. Monogame is like crossplatform framework and IDE  extension, and Cocos2D is an engine.

Comment: Thanks! Looking at cocos2d it looks really cool. Can't wait to get started with them.

Answer (score 1):

If you have XNA skills (or exising code) [Monogame](http://monogame.codeplex.com) allows you to reuse that and port it to Windows, iOS, Android very quickly.

If you are new, a popular new option is [Unity](http://unity3d.com). Their 4.3 beta has 2D support. They have a free intro SKU for indies, and you can get their add-ins to target Windows Phone and Windows for free.

Finally, if you are only targeting Windows Phone 8 (and maybe Windows 8) you can also use DirectX/Direct3D straight up.