# What Windows Phone 8/8.1 Dev API/Framework is an alternative of XNA app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xna

I need to rewrite a XNA app and deploy it on Window Phone 8/8.1.

My app requires extensive graphic presentation updated very frequently (kind of a game but not really) based on user's control. I am looking for an alternative API or framework so I can easily transfer the XNA code to the new platform (WP8/8.1).

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are my options for 2D games on Windows Phone 8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18892042/what-are-my-options-for-2d-games-on-windows-phone-8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into [MonoGame](http://www.monogame.net/). It is an open source implementation of the XNA framework and it can be deployed on multiple platforms (including WP8).